# Jasmine + Karma not working on Windows7-box with no internetconnection

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I've got a (what I think) strange problem with the test-setup of a Angular 2-project.

This is the setup:

-I've created a project by following this article: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html on a Windows10-box. Everything works fine and as expected. And for example: running "npm test" runs test as expected.

However, copying the projectfolder to a Windows7-box with no internetconnection gives the following error when running "npm test":

```
<code>
[1] 06 10 2016 11:31:34.822:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
[1] Chrome 23.0.1271 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'config'
[1]   at karma-test-shim.js:30
[1]
[1] Chrome 23.0.1271 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'config'
[1]   at karma-test-shim.js:30
</code>
```

I'm currently totaly out of ideas on how to solve this or what's wrong. Anybody that knows what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I solved it. Updating Chrome on the Windows7-box to the latest version fixed the problem :D